How to get top token holders? Fix the error with getTokenLargestAccounts
I was trying to fetch token holders information using getTokenLargestAccounts method.
client.get_token_largest_accounts(Pubkey.from_string(token_address))

This was my code.
It's working for some tokens.
for example: 2b1kV6DkPAnxd5ixfnxCpjxmKwqjjaYmCZfHsFu24GXo
But not working for USDC, USDT tokens.
Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB
EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v


The issue you're encountering is likely related to the fact that certain tokens, particularly popular stablecoins like USDC and USDT, have a very large number of accounts associated with them. The getTokenLargestAccounts method is designed to fetch the largest accounts holding a specific token, but it might run into limitations when dealing with tokens that have an extremely large number of accounts.
Also RPC nodes might enforce rate limits or have restrictions on the size of the data they can return. For tokens with a massive number of holders, this can be problematic. Storage of token accounts can be across multiple storage locations (shards), especially for very popular tokens like USDC or USDT. This could cause inconsistencies when querying the largest accounts.
Try Alternative RPC Nodes: Different RPC nodes might have different configurations in terms of caching, sharding, and rate limiting. Try using a different RPC node or service to see if that resolves the issue. For example, if you're using a public RPC endpoint, you could try switching to a dedicated node provider like QuickNode or Alchemy.
